# Anything wrong with necro-bumping?

Tags: discussion

I recently necro-bumped an [old challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11263/31224) from almost 4 years ago. I had an idea to start a similar challenge, but decided to just answer that challenge instead.

Is there anything wrong with digging up such old posts? My main concerns were that the original asker may not be active anymore to answer questions about the challenge, and it seems like common post formatting has changed (apparently people didn't specify "bytes" 4 years ago?).

Comment: I didn't know this either heh, we necrobumped the crap outta that challenge.

Comment: @carusocomputing Ya. I think it was a good thing to bump it though. It's a good challenge; although a little lacking in details.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with submitting answers to old challenges. We don't have any silly necroposting rules. In fact, you can even get some shiny rewards for it.

- The bronze [revival badge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/revival) is awarded for answering more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring 2 or more.
- The silver [necromancer badge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer) is awarded for answering a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more.

> It seems like common post formatting has changed (apparently people didn't specify "bytes" 4 years ago?).

Don't worry about it. The de facto default used to be characters, but we made bytes an explicit default some time ago. Just format your answer like you would if the challenge had been posted today.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: We even have a [Slowest Gun in the West](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11195/24877) category for *Best of PPCG*.