# Is it acceptable to answer an old question?

Tags: discussion

Is it alright to post an answer to an old challenge, in a language that hasn't been posted before?

I'm specifically asking about the following question: [Link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121118/golf-a-custom-fibonacci-sequence)

I happened across it, and wanted to post a new answer with PowerShell. I noticed, though, that the question has been inactive for many months. Would it still be OK to post my answer, and "revive" an old question?

Comment: Yes, why not? [This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life) is answered only after 4 years.

Comment: @user202729 It's a valid question. Many forums frown on "necroposting," or adding new replies to old threads. It's reasonable to suppose the same rule might apply here.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11309/anything-wrong-with-necro-bumping/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Yes

It's not only acceptable, but also encouraged! There are [several incentives for answering old questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12507/41024), and there are even two badges, [Revival](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/revival) and [Necromancer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer), that you can get this way.

Welcome to our site, and thanks for your desire to contribute!